# How to parse JavaScript array and put in c# array?

Tags: c#

I'll parse http://www.finam.ru/scripts/export.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that javascript data looks like comma seperated values, just remove javascript stuff like

- leading `var aEmitentIds=new Array(` and
- trailing `);`

and use csv library to parse the data.